# How do I get this script to run return the needed values of min max and sum

Tags: javascript, function

Here is the link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5e6yt/)

```
var num = prompt("Enter numbers seperated by spaces");
num = [];
var max = function (num) {
    var largest = num[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < num.length; i += 1) {
        if (num[i] > largest) {
            largest = num[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
};
var min = function (num) {
    var smallest = num[0];
    for (var i = 1; i > num.length; i -= 1) {
        if (num[i] > smallest) {
            smallest = num[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
};
var sum = function (num) {
};
return("Minimum is " + min + ", Maximum is " + max + ", Sum is " + sum + ".");
alert(return);
```

I need the script to return the numerical values in the sentence that is in in `return()`

Comment: there is a `return` statement but no function wrapping it. what is the point of that return statement?

Comment: That's cool, I need a new car. What have you tried and where exactly are you stuck? Did you try searching for how to sum numbers in JavaScript or how to find the maximal/minimal value?

Comment: I have the return statement to state which values to get from the functions is this wrong?

Comment: lol. Just put `alert("Minimum...")` Your return stuff doesnt make sense indeed.

Comment: @user3432271 what do you think `return` does? Also, JavaScript has all these kind of built in. Also, you're getting user input and then setting the array to an empty array.

Comment: @EricG I did that and then my return just came up with the functions for min and max and sum as a whole. I also tried replacing min and max with smallest and largest and that also didnt work

Comment: make a function `outputValues(){ var minimum=min(num), maximum = max(num), total = sum(num); alert( "Text" + minimum + " " + maximum); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned by [@JJPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22476633/1249581) you have multiple problems with your code. And you have to fix them if you want to make it working.

However if you want to learn new approaches, which could make your task easier and shorter, you may have a look at this alternative solution:

```
function worker(str) {
    var numbers = str.split(/\s+/).map(Number),
        max = Math.max.apply(this, numbers),
        min = Math.min.apply(this, numbers),
        sum = numbers.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });

    return 'Minimum is ' + min + ', Maximum is ' + max + ', Sum is ' + sum + '.';
}

alert( worker(prompt()) );
```

It does exactly what you want but here you use all power of JavaScript array and math methods.

Comment: this is great and sorry as you can obviously tell Im not very literate in script. where would my prompt be in this

Comment: Your answer is better :) +1

Comment: I feel this is the easier of the answers i just still cant input a prompt. i tried adding var num = prompt... but that didnt seem to work and the code stopped running

Comment: @VisioN is there a way to add prompt

Comment: @user3432271 `prompt()` is there in the code in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are reading from prompt and you initialized that variable to new array. Below lines. So you don't have any values left in num.

```
var num = prompt("Enter numbers seperated by spaces");
num = [];
```

Second, you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token return` because you have used return in a wrong way. Read about return by searching.

Third, you are not calling the methods min, max and sum properly.

An example code would be like below,

```
var num1 = prompt("Enter numbers seperated by spaces");
var num = num1.split(' ');
console.log(typeof (num));

var max = function (num) {
    var largest = num[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < num.length; i += 1) {
        if (num[i] > largest) {
            largest = num[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
};
var min = function (num) {
    var smallest = num[0];
    for (var i = 1; i > num.length; i -= 1) {
        if (num[i] > smallest) {
            smallest = num[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
};
var sum = function (num) {
};
alert("Minimum is " + min(num) + ", Maximum is " + max(num) + ", Sum is " + sum(num) + ".");
```

EDIT :
replace the sum with below. Adding a return statement would solve undefined problem.

```
var sum = function (num) {
     var s = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        s = s + parseInt(num[i], 10);
     }
     return s;
};
```

Comment: this works great minus my mistake on the sum function is there a way to fix the sum function so it will give me an actual sum as opposed to undefined

Comment: @user3432271 one way would be to sum the numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

`return` returns values from a function. One solution here is to take the user-input, add it as parameter when you call a function and have the result of that function return you the information you need. Here's your code rewritten to use the short-hand versions that JS allows:

```
var num = prompt("Enter numbers separated by spaces");

function getValues(num) {

  // split the user input into an array
  // and convert the string values to integers
  var arr = num.split(' ').map(Number);

  // Use the Math functions to get the max and min values from the array
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);

  // Reduce allows you to grab the sum of the values
  var sum = arr.reduce(function (p, c) { return p + c; });

  // return an object with all the values attached
  return { max: max, min: min, sum: sum };
}

// get the result by passing in num
var result = getValues(num);

console.log(result); //  { max=66, min=1, sum=79 }
console.log(result.max) // 66
console.log(result.min) // 1
console.log(result.sum) // 79
```

Hope it's of some use.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/2s8dQ/)**